# WCF catch custom FaultException

Tags: wcf, faultexception

I Want to use custome FaultException like this

```
 [DataContract]
public class Fault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class MyFault<T>:FaultException<T> where T : Fault
{
     public MyFault(T faultClass)
        : base(faultClass, new FaultReason(faultClass.Message))
    {

    }
}
```

...

```
throw new MyFault<Fault>(new Fault {Message = "hello"});
```

...

Interface

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(Fault))]
string GetData2(int value);
```

but when it get to the client it's transform to FaultException

```
      try
        {
            var res = serv.GetData2(1);
        }
        catch (MyFault<WcfService1Sample.Fault> ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Reason.ToString(); //-> i want here
        }
        catch (FaultException<ServiceReference1.Fault> ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Reason.ToString(); //-> catch here
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

can i catch custom fault on clint ? 
or the WCF automatic convert it to FaultException
how do i make this issue work

thanks kfir

Comment: Your `Fault` class should have a `DataContract` attribute, and the `Message` property should be a `DataMember`.

Comment: you right i forget to put data contract.  but even if i add it it dosnt work lik i want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues, I think.  First:

- What [shambulator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351301/shambulator) said: Your custom `Fault` class must be

  - a `DataContract`, and use
  - `DataMember` to mark all properties that shall be serialized.

If this is done, then WCF will

- translate a service-side `throw new FaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault { ... });` into a message which contains your fault, including the data; and
- translate this fault on the client-side to a `FaultException<MyFault>`.

Second:

This client-side `FaultException<>` is generated by WCF.  Maybe one can register a custom Exception-Translator, but I have never used it, never needed it, and not found such a thing after a one-minute Google search.  I'd recommend just going with the `FaultException` plus custom Fault-type.

Comment: thanks.  you right i search more the then a min i google and could find it, that why i post it.   you maybe right i could use regular FaultException